# Covariance (or correlation) matrix of coefficients in lme

Tags: r

I fitted a linear mixed model using lme function of nlme package.
'Summary' command shows the coefficients, their standard errors and correlation matrix of the coefficients.
How can I get this correlation matrix (covariance matrix is also fine) in a R data set form?

lm command (for linear model) do provide a covariance matrix in the object 'summary(lm5)$cov.unscaled'. I want to find a counterpart of this in lme function.

Comment: Read the package documentation. There are are full set of extractor functions.

Comment: Specifically you can use `help(package="nlme")` to see all the functions in a package. Or you can use `methods(class="lme")` to see all the functions that have a method for the "lme" class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the variance-covariance matrix of the fixed effects, use

```
vcov(fitted.model)
```

If you want the correlation matrix, use

```
cov2cor(vcov(fitted.model))
```

You can also use

```
summary(fitted.model)$corFixed
```

(use `str(summary(fitted.model))` to find the bits you need), but the accessors above are better because they don't make use of the (not necessarily stable) internal structure of the results.