# How can I get the covariance matrix of the coefficients when running a linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, covariance-matrix

I'm running a multiple linear regression with the `lm()` function and I would like to get the covariance matrix of the estimated coefficients. How can I do that?

Here [Covariance (or correlation) matrix of coefficients in lme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477848/covariance-or-correlation-matrix-of-coefficients-in-lme) there is an answer for the `lme()` function and I was wondering if the same can be done for the `lm()`.
Thanks!

Comment: This works, no ? `lm_mod<-lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length+Petal.Length,iris)
vcov(lm_mod)` Or **Self promotion, use the dev version of `manymodelr`**: `manymodelr::get_var_corr_(lm_mod$model)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Covariance (or correlation) matrix of coefficients in lme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477848/covariance-or-correlation-matrix-of-coefficients-in-lme)